# center multiple divs in single row using Foundation

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation for a web project within a CMS.
There is one content-element with a column count of 3. Depending on the data in the CMS there is a variable amount of elements. Let's assume 3 or any other uneven number. How can i archieve to center them in a row without completely breaking out of Foundation?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote my own sass for half column offset. That worked.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.0625em) {
    .large_offset_0_5 {
        margin-left: 100/24 *1%;
    }
    .large_offset_1_5 {
        margin-left: 100/24 * 3%;
    }
    .large_offset_2_5 {
        margin-left: 100/24 * 5%;
    }
    .large_offset_3_5 {
        margin-left: 100/24 * 7%;
    }
    .large_offset_4_5 {
        margin-left: 100/24 * 9%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.0625em) {
    .medium_offset_0_5 {
        margin-left: 100/24 *1%;
    }
    .medium_offset_1_5 {
        margin-left: 100/24 * 3%;
    }
    .medium_offset_2_5 {
        margin-left: 100/24 * 5%;
    }
    .medium_offset_3_5 {
        margin-left: 100/24 * 7%;
    }
    .medium_offset_4_5 {
        margin-left: 100/24 * 9%;
    }
}
```